# How to move a div using CSS or javascript within parent container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transforms

I am trying to use [Bootstrap plugin](http://lodev09.github.io/bootstrap-suggest/) which provides auto complete feature. While this plugin works well but at times when user is typing closer to border of the text box, the autocomplete div goes outside the textbox. See below image for more information.

How can I using CSS or JavaScript ensure that the auto comeplete div never goes outside the textbox?

[image]

Comment: Not really an answer to the question itself, but the linked docs state that you can set the `position` parameter to `"bottom"` instead of the default `"caret"`. Using a different position for smaller screen resolutions may work.

Comment: @ppajer: Thank you for the hint. I did looked at that property and it using `position:bottom` would result in auto complete div to be shown below the textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hook into the `show` event and check whether the popup is getting near the right border of the `textarea` (or whatever rule you wish to implement). If it is then change the dropdown's position so it displays on  the left side of the caret:

```
onshow: function (e) {
  var $dropdown = this.$dropdown.find('.dropdown-menu');
  var textAreaWidth = this.$element.width();
  var dropdownWidth = $dropdown.width();
  var dropdownLeft = $dropdown.position().left;

  // display left of caret if menu gets near right textarea border
  if (dropdownLeft + dropdownWidth >= textAreaWidth)
  {
    $dropdown.css({left: dropdownLeft - dropdownWidth});
  }
}
```

Full demo: https://jsfiddle.net/dowxo2jk/1/